# Jenkins Job gets created without Build Steps Powershell Jenkins Automation

Tags: xml, powershell, rest, jenkins, automation

My team has an online Jenkins on a VM and we are all using that. We want to install Jenkins locally for testing purposes and multi tasking.
I wrote a script that gets all the jobs from the online Jenkins and uploads them to my local Jenkins.
The problem is that the job gets uploaded without the build steps. But when I look into the config.xml, the steps are there, but they simply aren't displayed on the dashboard and they aren't run.

This is how I upload them:

```
$headers = @{'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$($Username):$($Password)")); 'Jenkins-Crumb' = $Crumb }
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest `
            -Uri "$($Url)createItem?name=$JobName" `
            -Headers $headers `
            -ContentType "text/xml" `
            -Body $JobConfig `
            -WebSession $Global:crumbSession `
            -Method Post
```

What I suspect is that when I look at the config.xml of the online Jenkins, the config looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description>
```

but the one that get's uploaded on my local Jenkins looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description>
```

There is a slight difference between them, the single quote and the double quote for example, aswell as some HTML entities that are being converted.
Other than this, I have no clue why it isn't displaying the build steps, as I mentioned the builders tag is there in both configs, exactly the same but it simply won't appear on the dashboard and it won't get runned.

Thanks for the read :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some digging, I managed to find the root cause of this. The problem is that the versions of the two Jenkins are different. The online Jenkins has a version of 2.176.3 and my local Jenkins is a little higher 2.222.4. Loading a job from an old version to a new one leads to some errors while loading the job. Apperently backwards compatibility isn't a thing for Jenkins :).